# Cron job - Vacationmode

Tags: magento-1.7

after installing a few cron tasks for auto sitemap creation/submission, I came across a cron task which seems to be running many times a day.

This might be an amature question but I haven't been able to find any information about it online.

Task: **cronjob_vacationmode**

Could anyone tell me exactly what this is and how (if needed) to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not part of a plain Magento 1.7 installation. You should search for "cronjob_vacationmode" in all extension configuration files (`app/code/**/config.xml`) to find out, where it comes from.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It was indeed a part of a previously installed extension and it is now no longer clogging up my Cron task list.